# QNetworkAccessManager can not get any HTML

Tags: qt

We use `QNetworkAccessManager` to request a remote URL, but we have a problem : it can not get any html, even though it can get the response body size.

This is the code:

```
   manager=new QNetworkAccessManager(0);
    cookie = new QNetworkCookieJar(0);
    manager->setCookieJar(cookie);
    QString str_url="http://www.wangdaizhijia.com/daohang.html";
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(str_url));
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8");
    request.setRawHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    request.setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    request.setRawHeader("DNT","1");
    request.setRawHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36");
QNetworkReply *reply=manager->get(request);
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),&eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),&eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    timer.start(5*1000);
    eventLoop.exec();
    if(!timer.isActive())
    {
        timer.stop();
    }
    QByteArray temp=reply->readAll();
    qDebug()<<"size is"<<temp.size();
    qDebug()<<"html is"<<temp;
```

If we request another url, e.g. http://www.google.com, it's working. Why?

Comment: looks like Timer is getting expired before you get reply. but as @iziseo suggested, why are you creating Event Loop and not using default signal slot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is an error in your code:

```
if(!timer.isActive())
{
    timer.stop();
}
```

should be

```
if(timer.isActive())
{
    timer.stop();
}
```

From your code, I can see that you are waiting for an answer using QEventLoop. QTimer is used to stop the loop when the remote server takes too long to respond.

You should check if QNetworkReply has finished, so your code should look like this:

```
eventLoop.exec();
if(timer.isActive())
{
    timer.stop();
}
if(!reply->isFinished())
{
    qDebug() << "Error request timed out";
    return;
}
```

Comment: hi firescreamer, im tryed,problems still exist,s suspect the html compress or other problems

Comment: This code works for me, but I hit timeout few times for that site. Increase timeout and see if You still have a problem. You can also listen to QNetworkReply::​downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) signal to know how much data was already downloaded.

Comment: hi firescreamer, it's work now.but i use read not finished signal,thank you answer my qustion.

Answer (score 1):

I always read the content of the QNetworkReply object from inside the slot connected to its *finished* signal. That's the way to guarantee that the reply object is ready to be read from.

I'm not sure why you need the event loop in this case.

Just try connecting the *finished* signal to a function and moving this bit to that function:

```
QByteArray temp = reply - > readAll();
qDebug() << "size is" << temp.size();
qDebug() << "html is" << temp;
```